Shower screws leaks when tuned back on
I replaced the cartridge for my delta faucet for bathtub. I have shut off screws to shut water off. I tested it on and off multiple times and it didn’t leak. Now when I turn the cold water back on it sprays water from screw.  Could the nut be lose. The hot water side is fine.

Yes the nut could be loose.  The seal could be compromised as they are not engineered to be opened and closed multiple times.  Start with checking if the lock nut is loose.
